# SQL divide sum by another value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a view using oracle sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS SELECT 
       [various other columns ommited],
       SUM (mt.Quantity) as "MY_QUANTITY",
       SUM (mt.Quantity) / at.VALUE as "EXPECTED_QUANTITY",
       [more columns ommited]

  FROM MY_TABLE mt LEFT JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE at ON mt.PK = at.FK 
  GROUP BY [various other columns that were ommited]
```

The problem I get is on the line with division. If I remove it, view gets created successfuly.
My question is how to divide the sum. I have tried using "MY_QUANTITY" alias instead of the sum on that line but as I understand this doesn't work.
The error I am getting is "not a GROUP BY expression".

**EDIT** to answer comments:
if I add "SUM (mt.Quantity) / at.VALUE" into my group by, I get a warning of "Syntax error. Partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams)". If I try to add alias instead, I get "invalid identifier" error

Comment: What happens if you add that column to the GROUP BY, do you get the expected result?

Comment: A good way to think of it is that anything not in your group by or being aggregated is gone after you aggregate your data.  So if it's not included in the group by  or aggregation you can't use it in any calculations.

Comment: added information about including it to group by @jarlh

Comment: @Bee_Riii how could I do that division line in the aggregation? The goal is for it to be a column value

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer here.

Comment: For the line with the division, mt.Quantity is in an aggregate, at.Value is not.
SUM(mt.Quantity / at.VALUE) will have both as an aggregate

Comment: @Jan this worked. View got created successfully. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jan It may be `SUM (mt.Quantity) / sum(at.VALUE)` also, which is a more common case.

Comment: So true @astentx, the granularity and relationship of "various other columns"  would have an impact.  A successful create does not guarantee data integrity

Comment: row SUM(mt.quantity)/at.value should be rewritten as

Answer (score 0):

There is something odd in the question. If you join the tables mt and at by mt primary key there is just one row from table mt affected by aggregation  meaning that there is nothing to sum from mt table. If sample data looks something like this:

```sql
With
    my_table AS
        (
            Select 1 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 1' "PK_NAME", 10 "QUANTITY", 1 "Q_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 2' "PK_NAME", 12 "QUANTITY", 1 "Q_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 3' "PK_NAME", 14 "QUANTITY", 2 "Q_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 4' "PK_NAME", 12 "QUANTITY", 2 "Q_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 5' "PK_NAME", 10 "QUANTITY", 3 "Q_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "MT_PK", 'PK_NAME 6' "PK_NAME", 16 "QUANTITY", 3 "Q_ID" From Dual
        ),
    another_table AS
        (
            Select 'A_100' "AT_PK", 1 "FK_MT", 14 "AT_VALUE", 'A' "AT_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A_200' "AT_PK", 2 "FK_MT", 15 "AT_VALUE", 'B' "AT_TYPE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A_300' "AT_PK", 3 "FK_MT", 16 "AT_VALUE", 'C' "AT_TYPE" From Dual
        )
```

... and if you join the tables ON(mt.MT_PK = at.FK_MT) then the SQL with or without summing gives the same result

```sql
SELECT
    mt.MT_PK "ID",
    mt.PK_NAME "NAME",
    at.AT_TYPE "AT_TYPE",
    Sum(mt.QUANTITY) "QUANTITY",
    Sum(mt.QUANTITY) / at.AT_VALUE  "EXPECTED_VALUE"
FROM
    my_table mt
LEFT JOIN
    another_table at ON(at.FK_MT = mt.MT_PK)
GROUP BY
    mt.MT_PK,
    mt.PK_NAME,
    at.AT_TYPE,
    at.AT_VALUE
ORDER BY 
  mt.MT_PK
--
--  above and below queries results the same  -----
--
SELECT
    mt.MT_PK "ID",
    mt.PK_NAME "NAME",
    at.AT_TYPE "AT_TYPE",
    mt.QUANTITY "QUANTITY",
    mt.QUANTITY / at.AT_VALUE  "EXPECTED_VALUE"
FROM
    my_table mt
LEFT JOIN
    another_table at ON(at.FK_MT = mt.MT_PK)
ORDER BY 
  mt.MT_PK
```

Result for both is...

```sql
/*
        ID NAME      AT_TYPE   QUANTITY EXPECTED_VALUE
---------- --------- ------- ---------- --------------
         1 PK_NAME 1 A               10     .714285714 
         2 PK_NAME 2 B               12             .8 
         3 PK_NAME 3 C               14           .875 
         4 PK_NAME 4                 12                
         5 PK_NAME 5                 10                
         6 PK_NAME 6                 16               
*/
```

... if there is another option to join the tables like Q_ID from sample data then...

```sql
SELECT
    mt.Q_ID "Q_ID",
    at.AT_TYPE "AT_TYPE",
    Sum(mt.QUANTITY) "QUANTITY",
    Sum(mt.QUANTITY) / at.AT_VALUE  "EXPECTED_VALUE"
FROM
    my_table mt
LEFT JOIN
    another_table at ON(at.FK_MT = mt.Q_ID)
GROUP BY
    mt.Q_ID,
    at.AT_TYPE,
    at.AT_VALUE
ORDER BY 
  mt.Q_ID
/*  R e s u l t :
      Q_ID AT_TYPE   QUANTITY EXPECTED_VALUE
---------- ------- ---------- --------------
         1 A               22     1.57142857 
         2 B               26     1.73333333 
         3 C               26          1.625
*/
```

Regards...